# Beam diameter of a fluoresence emitter after an objective

Tags: optics, microscopy

I try to calculate the beam diameter after a high NA objective that focuses on a point-like emitter that emits fluoresence light.

To my basic understanding, I get this by computing the Entrance pupil (EP) of the objective, thus
\begin{equation}
EP = 2*\mathrm{NA}*f_\mathrm{eff} = 2 * \mathrm{NA} * \frac{f_\mathrm{nom}}{X}
\end{equation}
where $\mathrm{NA}$ is the numerical aperture, $X$ the magnification and $f_\mathrm{eff}$ would be the effective focal length. However, this information seems not to be available anymore for modern objectives. I am looking at a [40x Olympus objective](https://www.olympus-lifescience.com/en/objectives/detail/0-DIRECTORY%3A%3ADirFrontend-itemId.511710234.html). I get the magnification, the Parfocalizing distance and the Back focal plane position as well as the objective field number. How can I get the beam width? Furthermore, if I compute the beam diameter like this, is this the $1/e^2$ diameter or the 99% diameter?

Comment: For small aperture, you could do a diffraction calculation, but for large aperture you need to account for aberration. I see no spec for that.

Comment: This is the sort of thing where you're more likely to get a useful answer by asking the manufacturer.

Comment: The $1/e^2$ diameter is useful in Gaussian beams. A Gaussian beam has no sharp edge. It fades away as you get farther from the axis. You make optics large enough so the intensity is small at the edge. This makes diffraction effects small. Your situation of a point source is different.